# Iterating over the elements of a structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, parameters, iterator

I have a class that is imitating a matlab like structure:

```
class params():
    maxresources = []
    functions = []
    terminals = []
    numvars = []
    initpoptype = []
```

All elements are lists, and my objective is to iterate them, to see for example if all of them are empty.

I have tried to use a    `def __iter__(self):` but it did not work, and i have also tried to use a `Enum` but also didn't work.

This is done on Python3.

Comment: Why don't you use a list or dict if you want an iterable container?

Comment: which one are you trying to iterate?

Comment: Why are all of those lists class attributes instead of instance attributes?

Comment: if all you have to do is check if the lists are empty, you don't need to iterate over them. Just check if the length is equal to zero

Comment: If you want to do stuff like checking if all the lists are empty then you should put them into a list, i.e., make a list of lists. Eg if `all_lists` is that lists of lists then `any(all_lists)` will return False if they're all empty, `all(all_lists)` will return False if any list is empty.

Comment: you probably just want to use a `collections.namedtuple` if you want something to emulate a struct. A class with a bunch of static attributes is not really a good way to do it. `namedtuples` will have the added-bonus of being immutable, memory-efficient, and directly iterable.

Comment: @juanpa,PM it may be because im not used to python but using either a dict or a list wasn't working for me, using a class as a sketchy struct of sorts worked just fine, except for this issue.

Comment: @juanpa i will look into those named tuples tho, they might come in handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do that or if using a class is the better way for your purpose but, to answer your question, you can read the class variables using:

```
params.__dict__.items()
```

this gives you

```
dict_items([('__module__', '__main__'), ('maxresources', []), ('functions', []), ('terminals', []), ('numvars', []), ('initpoptype', []), ('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'params' objects>), ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'params' objects>), ('__doc__', None)])
```

and from here you can iterate with the different vatiables like:

```
params.__dict__['maxresources']
```

or just iterate the tuples in dict_items

```
list(params.__dict__.items())
```

gives:

```
[('__module__', '__main__'),
 ('maxresources', []),
 ('functions', []),
 ('terminals', []),
 ('numvars', []),
 ('initpoptype', []),
 ('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'params' objects>),
 ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'params' objects>),
 ('__doc__', None)]
```

so you can check the object (second member in each tuple) corresponding to the names without underscores

Comment: Will the first and last three tuples always be those?

Comment: @eXistanCe you cannot rely on the order, it is *quite literally* a `dict`.